# How permutation order matters here?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to select a first-prize winner, a second-prize winner, and a third-prize winner from 100 different people who have entered a contest ?

This question is easy to solve as 1st prize can be given in 100 ways, then 2nd prize can be given in 99 ways and similarly, 3rd prize can be given in 98 ways, so total ways are => 100 * 99 * 98 => 970200 ways

---

But 100 * 99 * 98 = P(100,3) and since it is a permutation. ordering must be there but I don't see any ordering here.

Can anyone explain that what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is there because you have reasoned that there are:

- **100** options for the **first** prize,
- **99** options for the **second** prize,
- **98** options for the **third** prize.

The order in which you then calculate the product of these three numbers is of course, due to commutativity, not important. But their values result from taking the order into account.

Without taking order into account, you would simply need to *pick 3 people out of 100* and that's a combination of 3 out of 100:
$${100 \choose 3} = 161\,700$$
It's no coincidence that you find precisely $\tfrac{1}{6}$th of the answer with the permutation because there are $3!=6$ ways to order these 3 randomly chosen people into the three prize winning positions.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then order is (1,2,3) (2,1,3), (3,2,1).......  right ?

Comment: Yes and say you have three people A, B and C, then the 6 possible ways of ordering them into the prize winning positions are ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB and CBA. These are counted separately in the permutation-way, but not in the combination-way; that's the factor-6 difference.

Comment: Okk !! So, 1,2 and 3 can be placed anywhere among them . It is not  essential that one should always be first then second and then third , right ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question; but you don't have to start with the first place - if that's what you mean. The top-3 is also determined by first picking 1 out of 100 people for the 3rd place, then 1 out of the remaining 99 for e.g. the 1st place and then lastly 1 out of the remaining 98 for the second place. You get of course the same total number of possibilities to determine the top-3 (**with order**).

Comment: So, we can fill the 3 places in any order. This is what I mean, that there is no neccesity to first pick the topper and then second topper. I can start picking third topper then first and then second . Am I right now ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks !! Its cleared now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your calculation $P(100,3)=100\times99\times98$, you have written 100 possibilities for the first prize winner, 99 for second prize (as first prize winner can't also get the second prize simultaneously) etc.
  Suppose one of the counted possibilities was A as first prize winner, B the second prize winner  and C the third prize winner.

As our count for first prize possibilities was 100 
so B would also be counted as first prize winner (as B is part of the 100). Once first prize winner is fixed as B, for second prize you have written 99 possibilities, which is everything except the first prize winner B; this means A as second prize winner, and C as third prize winner will also  be accounted. And so on. So from ABC we could see BAC etc. This takes care of all permutations.

Is it clear now?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then order is (1,2,3) (2,1,3), (3,2,1)....... right ?